# How to pass a prop to match up with a state property in child in react-native

Tags: react-native

In my application, I created a timer component. This is a smart component because I wanted to handle the counter state inside the component.

this is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";


import { RoundedButton} from "../../mixing/UI"; 


class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            counter: 30
        }

        this.interval = null;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        cleanUp();
    }

    cleanUp = () => {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    decreaseCounter = () => {
        if (this.state.counter === 0) {
            return this.cleanUp();
        }

        this.setState({counter: this.state.counter - 1});
    }

    startCounter = () => {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.decreaseCounter, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <RoundedButton  text='Log in' onPress={() => this.startCounter()} />
                    <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
                <RoundedButton  text='Log in' onPress={() => this.cleanUp()} />
            </View>
        );
    }


}


// styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default Timer;
```

Now I want to call this from my parent screen. If I pass the counter as a prop,

Now the counter state can't be handled from Timer component. How can I handle the state of the child based on the parent prop.

Comment: `counter: props.counter`?

Comment: But, how can I achieve this?
 this.setState({counter: this.state.counter - 1});

Comment: you say that you want the counter to be controlled by the component. But you also say that you want to handle the state of the child (Timer) from the parent?

Answer (score 1):

you can use react component lifecycle `componentDidMount()`

`componentDidMount(){ 
    this.setState({counter: this.props.counter});
}`

There after you can use `this.setState({counter: this.state.counter - 1})`